# How to Format Displaying Users "MyBids"

Tags: usability, website-design, interaction-design, navigation, web-app

I am working on an Auction site and I am trying to show the users the items that they currently have bids on when they click "My Bids". The format I currently have it is to separate in two columns the Left for items they are "winning" the bidding and on the right items they have bid on but they have been "outbid". Like so:
[image]

I am not sure this is the best format for a use though because I think the user wont be able to quickly see all the items they are winning or losing and symmetry wise I don't want users to want to "balance" their outbid and winning.

I thought about maybe having Winning on top and then losing below but then I'm not sure how that would affect the user experience either. Please let me know what format for displaying the users bids is the most easy to read, while also encouraging the user to want to bid more to get more "winning items".

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following would work:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbUoxk.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This would provide an easily scannable list of items that would function as the users' bidding history.

Additionally, I could see it valuable to allow the user to sort these bids by various criteria, for example, bidding date, winning vs. losing bids, recent activity, and/or time remaining on the bid.

Comment: Thank you Max, this is a great way to index my items with useful information at a glance.

Answer (score 1):

Create one list where the current status of the bid is a property of the item. Take a look at the example below.

This way, the user can scan through one list and see the status of his bids by color (or text if the user is color blind).

[image]

Comment: Thank you Nick, I think I will combine Ma'x item layout with your ordering!